# Gulp proxy-middleware : how to set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp

I'm trying to get a bridge between my frontend app and backend app and Gulp documentation is quite poor about it.
I installed proxy-middleware.

The structure of the project is :

```
| Myproject
   | BackEnd App/ 
   | BackEnd config/
   | BackEnd folders/ ....
   | front/
      | app/
      | dist/
      gulpfile.js
      | other frontend folders/ here ...
```

This looks quite common.

So in my Gulpfile I have :

```
var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
...
gulp.task('connect', ['styles', 'fonts'], function () {
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
  var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
  var app = require('connect')()
    .use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))
    .use(serveStatic('.tmp'))
    .use(serveStatic('app'))
    .use('/bower_components', serveStatic('bower_components'))
    .use(serveIndex('app'))
        .use('/', proxy(url.parse('http://localhost:3000')));

  require('http').createServer(app)
    .listen(9000)
    .on('listening', function () {
      console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000');
    });
});

 gulp.task('serve', ['rails', 'connect', 'watch'], function () {
   require('opn')('http://localhost:9000');
 });
```

I know this seems weird ( / redirects to localhost:3000 ) and it probably generates the 500 of my assets (css and js)

Has anyone dig into this and found a solution or doc/tuto  ?

Comment: Also I tried to change path `.use('/', proxy(url.parse('http://localhost:3000')));` into `/app` with 404 instead.

Comment: No one ? up up up :D

Comment: Not posted as an answer since it isn't actually answering your question, but you can use gulp-connect-proxy to the same effect. See 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/samalexander/entry/using_gulp_connect_proxy_middleware_to_proxy_ajax_requests_in_gulp_connect?lang=en

Comment: http://lorefnon.me/2014/03/10/decoupling-frontend-with-gulp-and-node-http-proxy.html

Comment: Why not simply use browserSync as the proxy?